# Overloading output stream for my own class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, output

I have a base class Animal that class Cat and Dog derive from.

I'm trying to overload the output stream so I can do something like this:

```
Animal *a = (animal *) 0;
while(read_animal(cin, a) && a)       // a has been assigned a derived class
    cout << *a << '\n';
```

And here's how I've overloaded it:

```
 ostream& operator<<(ostream &a, const animal* animal) {
     return a << animal->describe() << endl;
}
```

But I get an error:

Error   20  error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'animal' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
cout << a << '\n';
```

Since your overload expects a `const animal* animal`

Alternatively change the signature of your function to:

```
 ostream& operator<<(ostream &a, const Animal& animal) {
     return a << animal.describe() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your overload expects `const animal*` but what you are supplying is `*a` i.e. `animal`, not `animal*`. So you may try:

```
cout << a << '\n';
```